# Get a php file and show contents on hover

Tags: jquery

When someone hovers over div.lol I want to show the contents inside profile.php on div.sdf

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lol').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().find('.sdf').get('profile.php');
    },function(){
        $(this).parent().next().find('.sdf').get();
    })
});
```

I tried this but nothing loads.

here is my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/csbVW/93/

Comment: Why not load it once rather than on every hover? This seems like a bad design.

Comment: I suggest you preload the content and show it on hover. On s slow connection it could take 2sec before content is loaded, which you dont really want on a hover

Comment: agree with @Martijn. If you really have to do this, load the content in the `<div>` element, add a `display:none` in the css (otherwise you can see it before the DOM loads,and that's horrible to my taste), then 
  `$('.lol').hover(function(){
    $('.sdf').show();
});` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `get` method wrong. Here is a [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) of get. The way you used `get` makes you call [this function](http://api.jquery.com/get/). Use `AJAX` `get` method to retrieve data from server and then inject result to the `DOM` element you want it displayed in.

Answer (score 1):

Linek is right about you not using the get method in the right way. You pass in a function as the second param, and use that to do what you want to do with the data returned from the GET call.

Something like the following should work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lol').hover(function(){
  loldiv = $(this).parent().next().find('.sdf');
  $.get('profile.php', function(data) {
    loldiv.html(data);
  });    
});
```